# How to create a class which can configure serilog for different events files using azure blob storage

Tags: .net, logging, serilog, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to add Serilog logging to my project (ASP .NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4.6.1)) and I can't get it past the actual logging of the statement.

string errorFile = DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Year + "_V2_Error.txt";

string infoFile = DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Year + "_V2_Info.txt";

```
        log = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
       .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
       .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(StorageAccount, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error, ContainerName, errorFile, null, true, null, null, true)
       .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
       .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
       .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(StorageAccount, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information, ContainerName, infoFile, null, true, null, null, true)
       .CreateLogger();
```

I am calling a different event as follows:

```
   public static void Error(string ErrorMessage)
       {
        try
        {

            log.Error($"Error: {ErrorMessage}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

  public static void Info(string ErrorMessage)
    {
        try
        {

            log.Information($"info: {ErrorMessage}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a serilog blob package to do it.https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage

Comment: What is the error message you receive? You also shouldn't have to wrap your logging calls with a `try...catch`. Calls to write to the logging are safe and do not throw

Answer (score 1):

In the package [Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage](https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage), you could use `LoggerConfiguration` to configure the log file format, and in the [Unit Test](https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage/blob/master/tests/Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage.UnitTest/BlobNameFactoryUT.cs) project there are some samples you could refer to.

The below is my test code.

```
            var connectionString = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("ConnnectionString");

            var bn = new BlobNameFactory("{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}_V2_Info.txt");
            var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(connectionString,LogEventLevel.Information,"logtest",bn.GetBlobName(new DateTimeOffset((DateTime.Now))))
                 .CreateLogger();

            log.Information("test information log");
```

And below is my result screenshot.

[image]

Comment: George, will it create every day new file or will it append to same file? Actually i need everyday to create new file.